# passing object with bundle returns null property

Tags: java, android

I've made a list of data that I'm trying to pass on to another activity.

```
public class MyData extends ParseObject implements Serializable {
    String name = "Tony";
    public String getName()
    {
        return getString("name");
    }
}
```

MyMainActivity:

```
List<MyData> data;
MyData temp;
```

so here's what I did:

```
temp = data.get(1);
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
i.putExtra("dataTag", temp);
startActivity(i);
```

and on the other activity...

```
MyData newFile;
newFile = (MyData) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("dataTag");
```

when I log the `newFile`, it returns the data as `ParseObject`. But when I try to get its attribute, such as name, etc. it returns null. I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try to log data.get(1).getName()

Comment: Why are you not using Parcelable instead of Serializable which more fater than Serializable in android.

Comment: @BlazeTama I tried it, it returns null.

Comment: So the problem exists even before you send the data. Show me the code how you add List<MyData> data and MyData temp

Comment: Check : http://www.easyinfogeek.com/2014/01/android-tutorial-two-methods-of-passing.html

Comment: @HareshChhelana i'll try to use parcelable and see if using parcelable solve my problem. thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7181792/1318946

Comment: @BlazeTama sure, when I check on the other activity, I log the newFile and it returns the object, but returns null when i try to get its property.

Comment: To create parcelable Class.....http://www.parcelabler.com/

Comment: @BlazeTama here's how i get the data

    result = DataDao.getData(); // DataDao.getData() ParseQuery to get data from database
    data.addAll(result);